# Nested layout problem in stripes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, stripes

I am experiencing some problems with the stripes layout. I will give a test case here:

Main Layout(main.jsp):

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/common/taglibs.jsp" %>

<s:layout-definition>    

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>{$title}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <s:layout-component name="body"/>
</body>
</html>

</s:layout-definition>
```

Sub Layout which is extending the main(sub_main.jsp):

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/common/taglibs.jsp" %>

<s:layout-definition>
    <s:layout-render name="/WEB-INF/jsp/common/main.jsp" title="${title}">
        <s:layout-component name="body">
            This is a test and this is from sub main
            <div style="color: red; font-size: 5em;">
                <s:layout-component name="subheader"/>
            </div>
            ${body}     
        </s:layout-component>
    </s:layout-render>
</s:layout-definition>
```

Now I am using the sub-main layout in the following code(test.jsp):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/common/taglibs.jsp" %>

<s:layout-render name="/WEB-INF/jsp/common/sub_main.jsp" title="Test Page">
    <s:layout-component name="subheader">
        This is from the sub header component
    </s:layout-component>
    <s:layout-component name="body">
        This is from body
    </s:layout-component>
</s:layout-render>
```

But in browser I am seeing the following:

> This is a test and this is from sub main 
>   This is from body

Instead of:

> This is a test and this is from sub main
>   This is from the sub header component
>   This is from body

Above all the title is displayed as:

> "$title".

Please any body can give me a clue about what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: @Keoki Zee, but this is specific to Stripes framework, isn't it ?

Comment: it is?  My apologies, I'll retag then.

Comment: @Kdeveloper, do you have any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that *subheader* is defined within the *body* component of the *sub_main.jsp* defenition, I don't think you can nest the component tags like that. You might want to try using a EL expression for the subheader instead (use: ${subheader}).

It's maybe best to always use EL expressions instead of layout-component tags when rendering the contents of a layout-component and only use layout-components for defining the layout. You can’t use layout-components for rendering while nested in a layout-definition (this dual usage of the layout-component is a design fault of the library and leads to unnecessary confusion in my opinion).

See also the [Nested Layouts](https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/display/STRIPES/Layout+Reuse#LayoutReuse-Nestedlayouts) section of the official Stripes documentation.

Comment: I read that article and made changes according to that. Now everything works fine except the title. Is there any hack for that ?

Comment: You should also add the title to the layout-render in sub_main.jsp: <s:layout-render name="/WEB-INF/jsp/common/main.jsp" title=${title}>

Comment: I have edited file as you advised.(I have edited in the question also). No use!!!